# prefix to infix in C

Tags: c, prefix, infix-notation

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node{
    char* data;
    struct Node* next;
};
typedef struct Node NODE;


NODE* push(NODE* top, char* item){
    NODE* newNode;
    newNode=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    newNode->next=NULL;
    newNode->data=item;
    if(top==NULL){
        top=newNode;
    }
    else{
        newNode->next=top;
        top=newNode;
    }
    return top;
}
char pop(NODE* top){
    NODE* temp=top;
    int i, returnValue;
    if(top==NULL){
        return top;
        returnValue='\0';
    }
    else{
        top=top->next;
        returnValue=temp->data;
        free(temp);
    }
    return returnValue;
}

void display(NODE* top){
    NODE* temp=top;
    while(temp->next!=NULL){
        printf("%c",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int isOperator(char c){
    switch(c)
    {
    case '*':
    case '/':
    case '+':
    case '-':
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

char* prefix_to_infix(char* expression){
    NODE* top;
    top=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    top->next=NULL;

    int i;
    for(i=strlen(expression)-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(isOperator(expression[i])){
                char a=pop(top);
                char b=pop(top);

                char temp[5]={'(',a,expression[i],b,')'};
                push(top,temp);
        }
        else{
            top=push(top, expression[i]);
        }
    }
    return top->data;
}

int main(){
    NODE* top;
    top=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    top->next=NULL;
    char expression[30];
    gets(expression);

    puts(prefix_to_infix(expression));
}
```

**Please Help, I've written this C code to print convert a prefix expression to infix expression. But the code would give some run-time error.**

*https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prefix-infix-conversion/*
*Above is the algorithm that I have used, and the only problem is in the implementation of the code*

**Explanation of the code**

*I have used Linked list to create my stack. I'm simply Inserting at head to push and deleting at head to pop.*
*In order to convert from prefix to infix, firstly I am taking in the expression(as character array) as an argument to the function prefix_to_infix().

Now I am checking if the element of expression is an operand or an operator.
->**If Operand** I am pushing it in stack.
->**If Operator** I am popping out the first two operands and merging them with the operator in between.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too many problems, check how to activate warnings in your compiler.

```
NODE* push(NODE* top, char* item){
```

The second parameter is expecting a `char *`, but you are passing a single `char` in

```
top=push(top, expression[i]);
```

This is also wrong:

```
char pop(NODE* top){
    NODE* temp=top;
    int i, returnValue;
    if(top==NULL){
        return top; /* You can not return NULL, pop returns a char */
        returnValue='\0'; /* This line is never reached */
    }
```

And here:

```
printf("%c",temp->data);
```

`temp->data` is a `char *`, use `"%s"` as format specifier.

Also, don't use `gets`, it's no longer part of the standard and it is very dangerous in previous versions, instead, use [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)

Finally, as pointed out in comments, don't cast the result of `malloc`

Comment: Good inputs there! +1. Additionally you can suggest getting rid of the useless casting there in `top=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));` , to check if `top` is NULL or not, also to free the memory that is allocated before exiting from `main`. :+)